# jQuery list simple fade in fade out slide issue

Tags: jquery

I created a simple slide effect using jquery. Here are the codes

**HTML**
(I'm on a condition that the HTML code can't be changed.)

```
<div class="wrp">
    <ul>
        <li>lorem ipsum one</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum two</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum three</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum four</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function () {
    var list_slideshow = jQuery(".wrp ul"),
        listItems = list_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen = listItems.length,
        i = 0,
        changeList = function () {
            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(300, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(300);
            });
        };
    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, 1000);
});
```

Jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/6Br9B/

My question is, if I leave the current page (tab) open, then the slide works fine. But when I switch to other tab then back to the page (let say after 5 seconds), the slide items will be displayed as stacked list. Please see http://goo.gl/aefEIk

Any idea why this happened? 
Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to shorten your code to this:

```
var i = 0;
function changeList() {
    var list = $('.wrp ul li');
    list.eq(i).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(300, function() {
        i++;
        if(i % list.length == 0) {
            i = 0;
        }
        changeList();
    });
}
changeList();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Br9B/1/)**

Comment: This works good. Thanks! It displayed the stacked list in the beginning of pageload so I added a small css to hide the list as default. Here's the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/RpB8L/

Comment: Umm sorry but I later found the interval between the is too short. How can I add the interval between the slide?

Comment: You can try to use [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/). Add it like `.delay(1000).fadeIn(1000).....`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, set some CSS to this `ul`.

#### DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/6Br9B/2/

#### CSS

```
ul {
    height:27px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is the length of the list items is not always same